# Accessing nested values in Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to access values in my Django template (using Jinja2) from an API and am struggling quite a bit. I'm new to Python/Django/programming and am having a hard time navigating through this complex nested structure of lists/dicts.

Here is a snippet of the API response for a single flight (the response contains a total of 250 flights):

```
{
    "meta": {
        "count": 2
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "flight-offer",
            "id": "1",
            "source": "GDS",
            "instantTicketingRequired": false,
            "nonHomogeneous": false,
            "oneWay": false,
            "lastTicketingDate": "2020-11-20",
            "numberOfBookableSeats": 2,
            "itineraries": [
                {
                    "duration": "PT22H40M",
                    "segments": [
                        {
                            "departure": {
                                "iataCode": "GIG",
                                "terminal": "2",
                                "at": "2020-12-01T16:30:00"
                            },
                            "arrival": {
                                "iataCode": "CDG",
                                "terminal": "2E",
                                "at": "2020-12-02T07:45:00"
                            },
                            "carrierCode": "AF",
                            "number": "443",
                            "aircraft": {
                                "code": "77W"
                            },
                            "operating": {
                                "carrierCode": "AF"
                            },
                            "duration": "PT11H15M",
                            "id": "3",
                            "numberOfStops": 0,
                            "blacklistedInEU": false
                        },
                        {
                            "departure": {...
```

For each flight I would like to extract the following key/values:

- id
- duration
- iataCode

Below is what I have tried so far...

**id (successful)**

```
  {% for flight in data %}
    {{ flight.id }}
  {% endfor %}
```

**iataCode (unsuccessful)**

```
  {% for flight in data %}
    {% for itinerary in itineraries %}
      {% for segment in segments %}
        {{ departure.iataCode }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

**iataCode (unsuccessful)**

```
  {% for itineraries, itinerary in data %}
    {% for segments, segment in itineraries %}
      {{ departure.iataCode }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Would be very appreciative of any advice here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "follow" the loop variable.

```
{% for flight in data %}
    {% for itinerary in flight.itineraries %}
      {% for segment in itinerary.segments %}
        {{ segment.departure.iataCode }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Borut - that makes a lot of sense, working now! :)